# Problems (Docker SDK for Python: docker (Python >= 2.7) or docker-py (Python 2.6)) on ansible-awx's Python /bin/python3

Tags: ansible-awx

**SUMMARY:**
I has done the installation ansible-awx follow the instruction:
https://howto.lintel.in/install-ansible-tower-awx-centos-7/

**ISSUE TYPE :**

When i ran command **ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml -vv**
in folder source awx /root/awx/installer

**Bug Report :**

TASK [local_docker : Start the containers] ********************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /root/awx/installer/roles/local_docker/tasks/compose.yml:39
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (Docker SDK for Python: docker (Python >= 2.7) or docker-py (Python 2.6)) on ansible-awx's Python /bin/python3. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter, for example via `pip install docker` or `pip install docker-py` (Python 2.6). The error was: No module named 'requests'"}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=13   changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=86   rescued=0    ignored=0

I try ran command with : **ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3'**
But error the error appears similar above .

**ANSIBLE VERSION**

ansible 2.9.10
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
executable location = /bin/ansible
python version = 2.7.5 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:16:51) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]

**OS:** CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same error and I solved it installing python36-docker and docker-componse.

```
yum install python3 python36-docker -y
pip3 install docker-compose
```

then rerun:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue, the following command executed on managed node (host) helped:

```sh
$ pip3 install docker
```